# JCacheManagerCustomizer does not work in Spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, ehcache

I have a spring boot and hibernate application that is using cache for Hibernate L2 cache. My caches are created through JSR107 configuration like below. Before migrating to Spring boot 2 this was working. But after migration, `cacheManagerCustomizer()` is correctly called but the `customize()` on the returned `JCacheManagerCustomizer`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@AutoConfigureBefore(value = {WebConfigurer.class, DatabaseConfiguration.class})
public class CacheConfiguration {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheConfiguration.class);
    private final javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> jcacheConfiguration;

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        log.info("Remove Cache Manager metrics");
        log.info("Closing Cache Manager");
    }

    public CacheConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        JHipsterProperties.Cache.Ehcache ehcache = jHipsterProperties.getCache().getEhcache();

        jcacheConfiguration = Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(
                CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class,
                        ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(ehcache.getMaxEntries()))
                        .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToLiveExpiration(java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(ehcache.getTimeToLiveSeconds())))
                        .build());
    }

    @Bean
    public JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer() {
        log.debug("Starting Ehcache");

        return cm -> {
            log.debug("Start  Customize"); // not called

            cm.createCache("baseInfoCache", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache("attachments", jcacheConfiguration);

        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `CacheConfiguration` listed as an autoconfiguration class in `META-INF/spring.factories`? If yes, add `JCacheCacheConfiguration` to `AutoConfigureBefore` and see if `AutoConfigureBefore.customize()` is called. If not, `JCacheCacheConfiguration` may be executing before `CacheConfiguration`.

Answer (score 0):

It should work flawlessly. So my current guess is that you have an issue with your Spring boot dependencies. If you have migrated JHipster 4 to Spring Boot 2, this is highly possible.

Another possibility is that your log is not set to the debug level. Have you debugged it to make sure it's called?

Comment: You've not provided any concrete suggestions, just a bunch of hypotheses.

Comment: Yes... since there are not enough detail to give a full diagnosis. I'm giving helpful possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. And I realised that I had two cache providers in the classpath (ehcache and hazelcast). After removing hazelcast, it works fine.

Now I have to find a way to define custom CacheManager bean that will be customized by the JCacheManagerCustomizer.